# Android Menu Inflater error

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get my menu inflater to link to my layout file, but when app launches and I hit menu, then select menu option it crashes program. It says it cannot find activity to launch:

error in eclipse LogCat:

01-01 10:24:38.799: E/AndroidRuntime(30359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.menu/com.menu.AboutUs}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.menu.AboutUs in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.menu-1.apk]

Main Code:

```
package menu;

import com.menu.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class testActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
     MenuInflater blowUp = getMenuInflater();
     blowUp.inflate(R.menu.new_menu, menu);
     return true;



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.aboutUs:
    Intent i = new Intent("menu.ABOUT");
    startActivity(i);
    break;
    case R.id.settings:

        break;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="menu.testActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity

        android:name=".AboutUs" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="menu.ABOUT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>







</application>

</manifest>
```

about.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:text="Why dosent this work???????????????????????  "
    android:title="About Us"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I would gratefully appreciate help... thank you

Comment: Have you added an action "menu.ABOUT" in the intent filter for an activity that you want to start on Menu option click?Also try removing the '.' in menu.ABOUT and use say menu_ABOUT

Comment: but menu is the package, and I'm simply decalring where the ABOUT is located no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got Class not found exception  for   com.menu.AboutUs -  pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch say Activity B from Activity A, you should make sure that you have declared Activity B in your manifest file.Then in your onOptionsItemSelected(), you can say,

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,B.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

If you want to start activity using Action parameter for intent you can use the following in the Activity tag in the mafifest.
This is considering activity B is in the application package directly

```
 <activity android:name=".B">
        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="menu.ABOUT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```